# Rename file after FileSplitter has finished

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

i'm currently designing a Integration flow in Spring Integration where I split a file with a **FileSplitter** handler and sending the results to another service. I'm currently handling "duplicate" files by using a **FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter** but I'd like to also add the functionality to rename a file after it has been read with a FileSplitter, what is the easiest way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileSplitter` has `markers` option. This way it produces a `START` and `END` messages. So, when you get an `END`, you can perform desired rename logic:

> Set to true to emit start/end of file marker messages before and after the file data. Markers are messages with FileSplitter.FileMarker payloads (with START and END values in the mark property). Markers might be used when sequentially processing files in a downstream flow where some lines are filtered. They enable the downstream processing to know when a file has been completely processed. In addition, a header file_marker containing START or END are added to these messages. The END marker includes a line count. If the file is empty, only START and END markers are emitted with 0 as the lineCount. Default: false. When true, apply-sequence is false by default. Also see markers-json.

There is a [sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/file-split-ftp) on with similar functionality.

Comment: Use a router to route the markers to one flow and the lines to another flow; on the marker flow, filter the START header and use the END header as a signal to rename the file.

Comment: You can also use a [`ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` on the splitter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice) and do the rename in the `onSuccessExpression`.